# PHP Laravel - Query Scope - Where ids contain a value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables and models:

1) Files

2) Visits

using query scope, I can get the total number of visits from particular dates:

```
public function scopeByDate($query, $start_date, $end_date)
{
    return $query->whereHas('visits', function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date)
    {
          $q->whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date));
    });
```

I can do that and this returns all of the files that have visits and these visits are made on a particular date.

As there is a relationship, I can, for each of of these returned files, get the visits by doing `$results = Files::ByDate($start, $end)`

The problem is that, this returns all of the visits by all of the users on this day. Let's say that I have 10 files and in that day, 5 of them are visited by `user 1` and `user 2` I want to limit to only showing the visits from `user 1`

NOTE: Inside the "Visits" there is a field called "user_id"

Is this possible? The users will be contained inside an array. `$users = [1, 2, 3, 4]` as an example

Comment: I haven't used scopes much, but couldn't you set up a `scopeByUsers` method and apply both? eg. `Files::ByDate($start, $end)->ByUsers($users)->get();`

Comment: @Kryten - I could, but, the problem is: I access the number of hits by `$file->hits);` which will return the number of resources WHEREAS I want to filter the resources that have a specific ID